# PHP output to export excel sheet

Tags: php, arrays, excel

My code output is like this which prints upto 100 table rows.

I want to export it in excel as well

```
<h2>Results</h2>
<table width=80%><tr><th width="40%">Head1</th><th nowrap width="20%">Head2</th><th nowrap width="20%">Head3</th></tr>
    <?php $count = count($abc);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
         $cont=round($abc[$i]->a);
         $pa = $p->get($abc[$i]->u);     
        echo "<tr><td><a href='" . $abc[$i]->u . "' target='_blank'>" . $abc[$i]->u . "</a></td><td align='center'>" . $cont . "</td><td align='center'>" . $pa . "</td></tr>";
    }
    ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question

Comment: The easiest way would be to simply send `header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");` and then output your table, but I would recommend using a CSV or PHPExcel as stated in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

try PHPOffice\PHPExcel library

https://github.com/PHPOffice

Answer (score 1):

this will create a csv file called output

```
if($fh = fopen("output.csv","w")){
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
        $cont=round($abc[$i]->a);
        $pa = $p->get($abc[$i]->u);     
        fputcsv($fh,array($abc[$i]->u,$cont,$pa));
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: This is not working, i want output as it was before, but extra little clickable link at end of output saying "Export in Excel Sheet"

Answer (score 1):

There's a little known trick that you can export a HTML Table directly into Excel.

Once you've generated your HTML Table, simply offer it as a download by setting the following headers:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xls");
```

Note that I would recommend removing your `<h2>` and any other HTML you have before doing this, so it leaves just a table. An advantage to this little trick is that it will save your formatting, too, so any bold text, background colours or whatever else is all preserved. Should the user want a "real" Excel file, they can simply save it out.

Another alternative is to output it as a CSV, or use a third-party library such as PHPExcel to achieve what you need. For such simple output, though, I'd recommend either a HTML Table to be opened in Excel, or CSV as the quickest routes.

Comment: Where to add these lines, also i want output as it was before, but extra little clickable link at end of output saying "Export in Excel Sheet"

Comment: @Kevin If you want a link, simply create a new PHP file with those lines at the top (because they're headers, and headers come before output), and the same table generation code that you have from your main page.

Comment: Of course, that little known trick will throw a warning when the file is opened in the most recent versions of MS Excel, telling you that the file format doesn't match the file extension - it makes you look really professional to your clients

Comment: @MarkBaker That's to be fully expected, type-safety n all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code below to get the output on excel

```
$csv_output.='\n';
$csv_output.='<h2>Results</h2>';

    $csv_output.='\n';

 for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
         $cont=round($abc[$i]->a);
         $pa = $p->get($abc[$i]->u);     
         $csv_output.= $abc[$i]->u . "," . $cont . "," . $pa . "\n";
    }


         header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
         header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
         header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
         print $csv_output;
```

So you need to create a comma seperated string of each 
\n denotes new line in excel

Comment: This code is ok, i understand, can you make it work with my variables as i mentioned in my code. The one you mentioned is easy one to understand how all this works, but i need to work with my 100 of rows output in dynamic way